# Issue with Highlight style changing on IE11 depending on the font color, how to keep it as default?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I'm using IE11.

When my font is black, if I highlight it shows, like in chrome, white font with blue background.

However if my font is orange, it displayed as blue with white background on IE11, unlike Chrome where it stays the same (white & blue).

I'm guessing this is something done for accesibility, but how can I change it so it always stays white & blue ?

Answer (score 1):

Put this is your css:

```
::selection{
    background-color: #338FFF;
    color:white;
  }
```

::selection refers to the highlight